# MySQL's now() +1 day

Tags: sql, mysql, datetime

I'm using `now()` in MySQL query.

```
INSERT INTO table SET data = '$data', date = now()
```

But I want to add 1 day to this date (so that `date` should contain tomorrow).
Is it possible?

Comment: DATE_ADD http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add

Answer (score 502, accepted):

You can use:

```
NOW() + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

If you are only interested in the date, not the date and time then you can use CURDATE instead of NOW:

```
CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

Comment: Or `DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)`

Comment: If more than 1, "day" does not become plural: "7 DAY", etc., is valid. (For those curious.)

Answer (score 11):

better use  quoted `` `data` `` and `` `date` ``. AFAIR these may be reserved words
my version is:

```
INSERT INTO `table` ( `data` , `date` ) VALUES('".$date."',NOW()+INTERVAL 1 DAY);
```

Answer (score 6):

Try doing: `INSERT INTO table(data, date) VALUES ('$data', now() + interval 1 day)`

Answer (score 5):

```
INSERT INTO `table` ( `data` , `date` ) VALUES('".$data."',NOW()+INTERVAL 1 DAY);
```

Answer (score 5):

Do you want to add time to a date value? MySQL interval values are used for date and time calculations. There are multiple ways to create an interval value.

One way is to use the following expression in your queries:

*date* [ **+** or **-** ] **INTERVAL** *value* [ **UNIT** ]

- **UNIT** is the type of interval to add/subtract. It can be one of the following values

|  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| MICROSECOND | SECOND | MINUTE |
| HOUR | DAY | WEEK |
| MONTH | QUARTER | YEAR |

*See the full list [**here**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/expressions.html#temporal-intervals)*.

- *Notice that the INTERVAL and UNIT are case-insensitive.*

Date arithmetic is less straightforward than time arithmetic due to the varying length of months and years, so MySQL provides [***special functions***](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html). Alternatively, you could use the **DATE_ADD()** or **DATE_SUB()** functions that add or subtract a time/date interval to a date value and then returns the result.

### Examples

```
-- Results were the same for all, '2018-05-02'

DATE_ADD('2018-05-01',INTERVAL 1 DAY);

'2018-05-01' + INTERVAL 1 DAY  

'2018-05-01' + INTERVAL 24 HOUR
```

---

### More examples

```
SELECT DATE_ADD('2100-12-31 23:59:59',INTERVAL '1:1' MINUTE_SECOND);-- '2101-01-01 00:01:00'

SELECT DATE_SUB('1998-01-02', INTERVAL 31 DAY);-- '1997-12-02'

INSERT INTO `table` ( `title` , `date` ) 
       VALUES('tomorrow never dies',NOW()+INTERVAL 1 DAY); --insert tomorrow date

SELECT DATE_ADD( NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY);--tomorrow date

SELECT NOW() + INTERVAL 1 DAY;--tomorrow date
```