# MySQL selecting rows where datetime is X days ago

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I have a table in database for meeting schedules. It has 2 columns named `start` and `end` and since I dont have access to the php script which fills this table with new data, I am not sure in which format it is.

But PHPMyAdmin shows taht the columns for start and end are `varchar(15)` So I guess it should be datetime compatible.

Example in DB: 1378033200
Which shows as 01 September 2013

My question is, I want to pull the meetings and show them in a html page, but I do not want meetings which are older than 2 days ago (server time) to show up. What will be the query?

```
SELECT * FROM schedules ORDER BY start
```

Something like

```
SELECT * FROM schedules ORDER BY start WHERE start > 2 days ago
```

I tried this but it seems it does nothing!

```
SELECT *
FROM schedules 
WHERE COALESCE(start, 0) < CURDATE() - INTERVAL 2 DAY 
ORDER BY start
```

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-date-functions.htm

Answer (score 1):

> But PHPMyAdmin shows taht the columns for start and end are
>   varchar(15) So I guess it should be datetime compatible.

You've guessed wrong. Strings are only sortable as strings. Which means, unless you're using a sortable date formats (`YYYY/MM/DD` being one: I'm not aware of others) you'll have to parse all the results and do the calculation by yourself in PHP (otherwise, 13/11/2000 will come before 14/01/2000). Alternatively, you might wanna use the proper type for your column: [datetime, date or timestamp](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html). Once you'll do that, [you'll be able to query your db and compare dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5182275/datetime-equal-or-greater-than-today-in-mysql) with `<` and `>` operators.

For the `2 days ago` part, you'd like to know that MySql has a built in [NOW](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now) variable to which [you can sum/subtract days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3887509/mysqls-now-1-day). If you'll design your db correctly, you won't even have to touch PHP (which a desiderable thing).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM schedules 
WHERE COALESCE(start, 0) < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 DAYS)
ORDER BY start
```

Comment: Where my own solotion was wrong, I think yours is also wrong.

Comment: @Saeid87 You think? did you even try my solution?

Comment: I can confirm this works!