# SQL Select from table where timestamp is greater than 1 hours ago

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a column in my table called `status_closed` which is a `datetime` column

how can i run a query to select all rows where the `status_closed` is not within 24 hours

Comment: It is sad no one is marking this clear duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

Use TIMESTAMPDIFF() function of mysql.

```
select * from Table where TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,status_closed,NOW())>24;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM `table`
WHERE status_closed < NOW() - INTERVAL 1 day
```

Comment: While this answer may solve the problem, you should elaborate on it a bit and explain what your code does.

Comment: You're wrong, the code describes itself well

Comment: Even if I find a correct code-only answer, I never upvote it because that only rewards/perpetuates the posting of more low-quality answers that care little about educating/empowering thousands of future researchers (who may or may not know a darn thing about the language that they are researching).

Comment: Should be the accepted answer. Self-explaining code.

Answer (score 0):

Subtracting a 1 day interval from `NOW()` will do the trick:

```
select 
  * 
from 
  table 
where 
  status_closed < NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

[For further reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3887517/2589202)

Answer (score 0):

Use the DATEADD function, and check to see if the status_closed is less than or equal to 24 hours before now.

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE status_closed <= DATEADD(HOUR, -24, GETDATE())
```