# MYSQL select data that is older then 2 years

Tags: php, mysql, date

So I want to purge some data from the system which is older then 2 years.

I have a datetime field where I store.

I know I can do something like

```
SELECT * FROM `table` where date_field < (??? what goes here)
```

My problem is i think how do I calculate the date, or maybe I am confused

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add may help you. `DATE_ADD(date,INTERVAL expr unit)`, `DATE_SUB(date,INTERVAL expr unit`) along with `now()`. also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3887509/mysqls-now-1-day

Comment: Wouldn't you need to use > now-2 years? instead of < though?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `INTERVAL`:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE date_field < DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 2 YEAR);
```

Referenced from https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html.

Answer (score 5):

For a specific answer in case the Manual isn't clear enough:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` where date_field < (now() - interval 2 year)
```

Answer (score 4):

Use DATE_SUB

```
SELECT * FROM `table` 
where date_field < DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 2 YEAR)
```

Comment: Sure about that < ? don't you mean > ?

Comment: Isn't he looking for a date prior to now - 2 years? So the dateField should be smaller than now -2 to match the correct data @xQbert

Answer (score 3):

may this can help :

```
SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM `date`) AS year 
from table 
having year< (EXTRACT(YEAR from CURDATE())-2)
```

Answer (score 1):

SELECT * FROM `table` where date_field <  DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 2 YEAR);

Comment: its simple, use now() function inside date_sub()