# get the date after 24 hour in mysql

Tags: mysql, datetime

I want to select in my DB times after 24 hours from curdate

For example:

> if i'm at 2018:7:4, then 18:05:00 and in my DB 2018:7:5 18:05:00 will be selected. If hour is different then 18:05:00 will not be selected .

I have tried this :

```
select*from t1  where date=(curdate()+ interval 1 day);
```

but it works just when the date is without time 2018:7:4 00:00:00,

```
select*from t1  where hour(date)=(hour(current_time())+ interval 24 hour);
```

and the above works just if the number of hours doesn't pass the middle of the night

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL's now() +1 day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3887509/mysqls-now-1-day)

Comment: i have tried it ,it dont work

Answer (score 0):

i have found the solution by myself

```
select * from t1  where DATEDIFF(date,curdate())=1 and hour(date)=hour(current_time()) and minute(date)=minute(current_time());
```

if i want just the date this is the query :`select * from t1  where DATEDIFF(date,curdate())=1`.

for hour or minute or both of them i use all the query .

if anyone can optimize the solution it will be better