# How to override value in NOW mysql function? I need to set past date in now function

Tags: php, mysql

I have set up cronjob wherein MySQL query there are used NOW SQL function at lots of time. I want to run cronjob for a past date so I need to change in code. But I think if I will change return static past date value in now function of SQL then I can do a thing without code change.

My current code in cronjob.

```
....
$query = "SELECT * from table_name where from_date <= DATE(NOW())";
....
```

Comment: And what is the problem with using MySQL's date function to offset `NOW()` by some amount?

Comment: I want to override the function "NOW" to change the value with past date instead of current date. Do you have idea about it?

Comment: You're looking for `INTERVAL` See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3887509/mysqls-now-1-day

Comment: This can't be done AFAIK.  Again, what is the problem with manually offsetting `NOW()` yourself?

Comment: No you have not understood my problem bro. I don't want change in code.

Comment: @Ultimater Do you know about the way of override NOW function of MYSQL??

Comment: Aside, why wrap `NOW()` in `DATE()`? `NOW()` is a datetime, no conversion needed.

Comment: NOW return "YYYY-MM-DD HH-MM-SS"  format and date function change the format to "YYYY-MM-DD". so  i use date() on now() function

Comment: @BhavinThummar if you only want the date, use `CURDATE()` in preference to `DATE(NOW())`

Answer (score 1):

You can set the system variable [timestamp](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_timestamp) to set a time that is returned by `NOW()`

Comment: You are nearer to my answer. I will check right now this thing.

Answer (score 0):

Why you need to override, Its not feasible? You can use past date instead of now as you specified in question!!

```
$query = "SELECT * from table_name where from_date <= 'yyyy-mm-dd H:i:S'";
$query = "SELECT * from table_name where from_date <= '2018-05-05 05:05:05'";
```

Comment: I am using lots of time now function  in php code. So i think we can change the return value of now function in mysql.

Comment: Do you know about the way of override NOW function of MYSQL?